# OpenGL 3+, как нарисовать 2 фигуры?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

Переписал код с шейдерами, и много что не понимаю! в данном коде нарисована только один квадрат! а как нарисовать еще что нибудь? Если допустим создать еще один массив, с координатами, а потом что? Нужно создать еще какой то шейдер или что?

```
#include <iostream>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using namespace std;

const GLint WIDTH = 1280, HEIGTH = 720;

short Lkey = 0;
short Rkey = 0;

float mausX;
float mausY;

static void cursorPositionCallback(GLFWwindow* window, double xPos, double yPos);

const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n"
"}";

const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 color;\n"
"void main () \n"
"{\n"
"color = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);\n"
"}";

void keyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);

int main() {

    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGTH, "Learn OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, cursorPositionCallback);

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;

    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight);
    if (nullptr == window) {
        cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (GLEW_OK != glewInit()) {
        cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];

    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        cout << "ERROR::SHADER::COMPILATION_FAILED" << infoLog << endl;
    }

    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        cout << "ERROR::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED" << infoLog << endl;
    }
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);

    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED" << infoLog << endl;
    }

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    GLfloat ver[]{
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,  
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    GLuint VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(ver), ver, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        cout << mausX << endl;
        cout << mausY << endl;

        glfwPollEvents();


        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glfwTerminate();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Нужно просто ещё раз вызвать функцию glDrawTriangles с уже новыми координатами. Писать новый шейдер для этого не имеет смысла, так как (в вашем случае) он нужен лишь для интерполяции.

Comment: ноо в  glDrawTriangles там нет где указывается массив с координаторами... этот массив указыается где то в шейдаре в  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(ver), ver, GL_STREAM_DRAW); как быть???

Comment: Чего? Где в шейдере, по вашему, у вас определены хоть какие-то массивы? В любом случае с glDrawTriangles лучше работать через vbo & ebo

Comment: если Вы хотите нарисовать еще один квадрат- у Вас 2 пути. либо новый буфер с вершинами и тот же шейдер, либо добавить сдвиг в шейдере, тогда вершины можно не менять

Answer (score 0):

Изменяем значения вершин в вершинном шейдере:

---

Добавтье в вершинный шейдер `uniform` переменную типа `vec2` под названием `translate`;

```
const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
"uniform vec2 translate;\n"
"void main() {\n"
"    gl_Position = vec4(position.xy + translate, position.z, 1.0);\n"
"}";
```

После линковки шейдеров в программу получите "указатель" на эту переменную:

```
GLint translateLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "translate");
assert(gScaleLocation != 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

А затем перед вызовом `glDrawArrays` или другого `"drawCall"` установите значения в этот `vec2`

```
glUniform2f(translateLocation, 0.1, 0.1);
```

Comment: '+ translate'  так не делается обычно....  есть же матричная алгебра gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0);

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков не спорю, это пример для понимания. тем более для только лишь перемещения матрицы избыточны.